# Mock a request for asynchronous processing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement asynchronous versions of some existing DRF API methods (particularly list methods) that can take a long time. My idea is to capture the authenticated user ID, what method he wants to execute and the query string; and then queue a task to run that method. It seems the simplest thing is for the task handler to create a mock request for the actual API method and then store the results somewhere for a poll handler to read.

My question is: How can I efficiently create a mock Django request (including user and query string) which would then be used to either directly create the view set or to dispatch the request to the appropriate url path? From an API standpoint, the Django test client actually seems to be a good fit for my intent, but I'm not sure whether it's a good thing to use in production or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's an excerpt:

```
from django.http import request, QueryDict

view_kwargs = view.kwargs
query_params = request.QUERY_PARAMS

req = request.HttpRequest()
req.user = user
req.method = 'GET'
req.GET = QueryDict(None).copy()
req.GET.update(query_params)

resp = viewset_class.as_view({'get': 'list'})(req, **view_kwargs).render()
```